# Node.js Discordie Bot Promise Rejection Error

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I'm getting a random promise rejection error, constantly. If you can help at all, that would be amazing :)

So, here's the situation. I made a bot for Discord, and it worked great for about 5 minutes (I'm just using basic code until I get used to it, BTW). But, for  no reason I can figure out, I now get the error bellow every time I try to use one of the commands built into my bot.

(node:9896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Forbidden (Missing Permissions)

I don't know how much knowing what my bot's coding looks like will help, I'm new to this (so I also don't know what part is giving me trouble), but I'll include the basic code bellow.

```
  var Discordie = require('discordie');

  const Events = Discordie.Events;
  const client = new Discordie();

  client.connect({
  token: 'Don't want to give out my token'
  });

  client.Dispatcher.on(Events.GATEWAY_READY, e => {
    console.log('connected as: ' + client.User.username);
    });

  require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 100;

  client.Dispatcher.on(Events.MESSAGE_CREATE, e => {
  if (e.message.content == 'PING') {
    e.message.channel.sendMessage('PONG');
    }
  });
```

There's a lot of code after this, and I really want to get it to work. Any suggestions are appreciated, just remember I'm a complete noob and speak to me like I'm an idiot:)

Comment: If it worked for five minutes, you're sure you didn't get thrown out of something for making too many requests or something similar.

Comment: I have no clue. As I said, I'm new to this. Would I get an unhandled promise rejection with that? If that is the case, how would I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're being rejected by either the server or you're not set as adminstrator.

You may have had your role revoked.

Comment: UNP-17 is right. Just had this error, this happens if the bot does not have permission to read or write in your channel.